# Magento 2 - how override some files of module-catalog-search in custom theme

Tags: magento2, php, theme, overrides, catalogsearch

I would override this files in my custom theme (app/design/frontend/parent/MyCustomTheme/..)

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Dynamic/DataProvider.php

vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/SelectBuilderForAttribute.php

vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Aggregation/DataProvider/QueryBuilder.php

vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Filter/Preprocessor.php
```

How can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You cannot override this file in theme under app/design folder

For that you need to create Module or Extension under app/code folder using preference

For example
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Adapter/Mysql/Dynamic/DataProvider.php

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Dynamic\DataProvider" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\DataProvider"/>
</config>
```

Then create file app/code/Vendor/Module/Rewrite/DataProvider.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Dynamic;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Adapter\Mysql\Dynamic\DataProvider
{

}
```

if it make you confuse to do custom code then just copy DataProvider.php and paste it in Rewrite folder and then change namespace accordingly

Thanks
Happy Coding

Comment: Perfect man! Thanks! One more question please. When i create a custom column in table "catalog_product_index_price" and reindex my custom column is removed and i see error in my website because column not exist. My override is for this operation. How can I make my reindex not clear the column?
Thanks

Comment: No idea but I think that happen because this column is kept for read/write operation for reindexing but you can try adding you column in both of this catalog_product_index_price, catalog_product_index_price_replica table use when catalog_product_price is reindexing. Might help you. But NOT RECOMMENDED

Comment: Thanks man so i will try in local for the moment. Have a nice day! ;)